# MySQL group on break value

Tags: mysql, group-by, colors, sequence, break

[enter image description here][1]
Hi All, I need your helps.
Left table is my data which is in ordered. Right table is my disired. I would like to group by Product and Color follow sequence?
Ex:

```
Product A - Color 1 - Sum Qty, 
Product A - Color 2 - Sum Qty,
Product A - Color 3 - Sum Qty,
**then again**,....
Product A - Color 1 - Sum Qty
```

.
Group by sequence, break the group by color which is in different.
Thank you!value
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaEor.jpg

Comment: What is your primary key? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: On the right table you have product "A" and color "1" on two rows? How should the database know which qty should go to which row? Or is is based on the order from the left table??